# :animated selector to wait for animation menu to finish

Tags: jquery, animation

I have this bit of code that waits for a menu to finish animation:

```
    if( $('#pc_lhs_top_ul').children(':animated').length > 0 ||
        $('#pc_lhs_bottom_ul').children(':animated').length > 0 || 
        $('#pc_lhs_top_ul:animated').length > 0 ||
        $('#pc_lhs_bottom_ul:animated').length )
    {
        return;
    }
```

when i use chrome inspector to inspect it, this bit of code is run every time i try to click on a link, which is my intention. but, if i click repeatedly very fast, at the exact moment the animation is finished, for some reason, clicking the link will not return.

after debugging alittle more i found out, that I have two separate animations, that are run one after the other, clicking on the anchor tag is disabled but right when the first animation is complete, it is not disabled, and animates again along with the second animation. there is some kind of time gap that there is no animation.  should i add a delay after the first animation ?

Comment: might do better toggling a flag in your animation sequence and check for flag instead

Comment: thats a good idea, is there any other ways though with jquery?

Comment: hard to answer without seeing your animation code. Most of the time `stop()` is very handy in nav animations since mouse moves a lot through nav

Comment: The code above doesn't "wait for a menu to finish animation". It tests whether animations are currently in progress, which is very different. I think what you want is to fire a custom event at the point of interest - presumably when the whole animation sequence is complete. Thus, you have the means of establishing a handler to perform whatever is required, at that point of interest.